# scala MatchError in creating tuple from Pattern Matching

Tags: scala, tuples, pattern-matching

I have written the following code:

```
case class Filters(city: List[String], isType: List[String])

val input = "BNG:school | HYD:school,restaurant"

val(filter1:Filters, filter2:Filters) = input.split("\\|") match {
  case Array(f1, f2) => (f1.split(":") match {
      case Array(c,t) => t match {
        case _ if t contains "," => Filters(List(c.trim), t.split(",").map(_.trim).toList)
        case _ => Filters(List(c.trim), List(t.trim))
      }
    },
    f2.split(":") match {
      case Array(c,t) => t match {
        case _ if t contains "," => Filters(List(c.trim), t.split(",").map(_.trim).toList)
        case _ => Filters(List(c.trim), List(t.trim))
    }
  })
  case _ => (input.split(":") match {
    case Array(x,y) => Filters(List(x.trim), List(y.trim))
  },Nil)
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
filter1: Filters = Filters(List(BNG),List(school))
filter2: Filters = Filters(List(HYD),List(school, restaurant))
```

But if I change the input to : `val input = "BNG:school"`

the output gives error:

`Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: (Filters(List(BNG),List(school)),List()) (of class scala.Tuple2)`

I don't know what am I doing wrong?
I have three types of inputs:

```
BNG:school
HYD:school,restaurant
BNG:school | HYD:school,restaurant
```

The code is supposed to work for these types of inputs.

**Secondly:**
If I remove the datatype Filters from filter1 and filter2
it gives the output as:

```
filter1: Filters = Filters(List(BNG),List(school))
filter2: Product with Serializable = Filters(List(HYD),List(school, restaurant))
```

Why **filter1** is of **Filters** type and **filter2** is of **Product with Serializable** type?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First I would recommend you to improve the formatting of your code, right now it is quite difficult to read. Second, the problem is quite simple; here: `val(filter1: Filters, filter2: Filters) =` you are assuming the `match` will return a tuple of two **Filters**, however in your second case you return a tuple where the first element is a **Filter** bit the second one is an empty **List**, not sure why you think an empty list could be casted into a filter, or if you thought that empty list somehow would be ignored and the second filter variable simply wouldn't exist or whatever.

Comment: So, you need to think in a better alternative for not having a second **Filter** maybe you can use the **Option** datatype? Or maybe you would be good with a `null`? _(not idiomatic but familiar for people coming from imperative languages)_. Or maybe, instead of returning a tuple that `match` should return a **List** of **Filters**?

Comment: Third, for your second question. The trick here is type inference, the compiler has to determine which will be the return type of the whole `match`. So the compiler sees that both branches return a **Tuple** so it goes for that. Then, it sees that for both branches the first element of the **Tuple** is a **Fitler** so it goes with that. And finally, it sees that for the second element one branch returns a **Filter** and the other one returns an empty **List**, so it has to find the LUB _(least upper bound)_ between those two types and it turns out that **Product with Serializable** is that LUB

Comment: Thank you for your insight @[Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez). The third comment was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes that `input` contains 2 `Filter` strings. If it actually contains less than 2 or more than 2 then things break down.

This can be done by splitting the input multiple times, multiple ways.

```
val input = "BNG:school | HYD:school,restaurant|LND,HKG:restaurant"
input.split("\\s*\\|\\s*")
  .map { ss =>
    val Array(cs, ts) = ss.split("\\s*:\\s*")
    Filters(cs.split(",").toList, ts.split(",").toList)
  }.toList

//res0 = List(Filters(List(BNG),List(school))
//          , Filters(List(HYD),List(school, restaurant))
//          , Filters(List(LND, HKG),List(restaurant)))
```

Or you might use a regex pattern to help segregate the data elements.

```
val re = "([^|:]+):([^|:]+)".r
re.findAllMatchIn(input)
  .map(m => Filters(m.group(1).trim.split(",").toList
                   ,m.group(2).trim.split(",").toList)).toList
```

A big advantage here is that the regex search will simply skip badly formed data (like a missing `:` for example) instead of throwing an error.

---

The **regex** pattern explained:

- `[^|:]` - any character that is **not** (`^` means *not*) a bar `|` or a colon `:`
- `[^|:]+` - has to be at least 1 of those (`+` means *1-or-more*)
- `([^|:]+)` - remember that group (parens create a "capture group")
- `([^|:]+):([^|:]+)` - 2 capture groups (`group(1)` and `group(2)`) separated by a colon `:`. Each group consists of all the characters, before and after the colon, that are not bar or colon characters.

Comment: Thank you @[jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh). Worked like a charm. Plus I hadn't considered a second '|' in the input string. This helped a lot.

Comment: Just a follow up question @[jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh). In the **BNG:school** doesn't have a ',' in cs part of the Array(cs, ts) so how does the `Filters(cs.split(",").toList` gives the `cs`. I mean how the split is skipped in this. **Secondly**: can you explain me the regex used.

Comment: @HasnainMotagamwala; `split()` returns `Array[String]`. If the string can't be split then it returns an `Array` with 1 element, the original and unchanged `String`. The **regex** explanation has been added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter says, it's because you have a tuple on the left hand side of the equality.

Maybe something along the following lines are better?

```scala
case class Filters(city: List[String], isType: List[String])

val regex = "(\\w+):([,\\w]+)".r
val input = "BNG:school | HYD:school,restaurant"

val result = input.split("\\|").map(regex.findFirstMatchIn).map {
  case Some(m) => Filters(List(m.group(1)), m.group(2).split(",").toList)
  case None => throw new Exception("No match")
}

println(result) // Array(Filters(List("BNG"), List("school")), Filters(List("HYD"), List("school", "restaurant")))
```

Also beware of https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5365 on 2.12 when using if-guards in match blocks.

Comment: thank you @[gogstad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576149/gogstad). This helped me to know about Option Type in Pattern Matcing. But I am not looking for throwing exception.

Comment: Regardless of how you express the pattern matching, you need to handle the case of "no match". If you don't want to throw an exception, simply capture the result in a structure that can encode that failure state (like `Try`, `Either`, `Option`, Validated...)